# How much weight is lifted from each side?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, friction

I don't know the math to do this, so I am asking here if someone can work this out with all of the details I'm providing.

Total mass EST.: 2,400 lbs.

Length from front to back: 14 feet 6 inches.

Ground clearance (space between floor and bottom of car base): 4.7 inches.

Height (from ground to top of roof): 4 feet and 5.7 inches.

Wheelbase (distance from center of front and rear wheels): 8 feet and 1 inch.

My simple question is, how much force would it take to lift the back and front of the car from the bumpers in the air?

If you want to really answer another question, **how much is lifted from one-side of either the back and front wheels**?

The front bumper is a bit closer to the ground compared to the back one (almost 2 inches), so lifting depth must account somewhat. Last, the surface is very flat paved cement.

Someone told me with a ballpark guess that the back is 600 lbs., one-side of the back is 240 lbs., one-side of the front is 565 lbs., and the whole front is 1,130 lbs.

Comment: None of the heights matter. What does matter is how the weight is distributed. Is the weight more toward the front, or more toward the back? Is it concentrated in the middle, or is a lot of it in the very ends? Are you lifting both ends at the same time, or one end at a time?